# Scraping sport bookie

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape a sport website but I keep hitting on problems.

Bookie: https://fezbet1.com/en/sport?sportids=1

All imports etc. are right !

Code:

```
frame_ref = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0]
iframe = driver.switch_to.frame(frame_ref)

Odds = WebDriverWait(10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'asb-flex-cc asb-cut asb-pos-stretch _asb_events-table-row-markets--price-block-content _asb_price-block-content')))
```

Error:

```
rows = WebDriverWait(10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'asb-flex-cc asb-cut asb-pos-stretch _asb_events-table-row-markets--price-block-content _asb_price-block-content')))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timeout'
```

I don't thine I have much more information to give
Please help me, and thanks for you're time !!!

Comment: error shows that you forgot argument `timeout` - better read documentation for [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I have a new problem: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Senne\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    Odds = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'asb-flex-cc asb-cut asb-pos-stretch _asb_events-table-row-markets--price-block-content _asb_price-block-content')))
  File "C:\Users\Senne\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page - you will have more space for error message and explanation. Stackoverflow is not forum. Aht this error can means that it can't find element. And yoiu should add all information what you do - i.e real URL for this page, minimal working code which we could run.

Comment: string `'asb-flex-cc asb-cut asb-pos-stretch _asb_events-table-row-markets--price-block-content _asb_price-block-content'` is many classes but `Selenium` can work only with one class - you may need to use dot between classes to workaround problem `'asb-flex-cc.asb-cut.asb-pos-stretch._asb_events-table-row-markets--price-block-content._asb_price-block-content'` (like in CSS selection) OR you should use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `By.CLASS_NAME` with correct CSS selector

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

You forgot `driver`

---

Selenium doc: [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: looks to be fix for the above issue, but OP heading confused me :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys I really really apriciate it !!

but now after some further coding I stumble on the next problem
I want to get the information but It seems like I still can't extract the data
I don't get an Error message just:

C:\Users\Senne\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Senne/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Teams, btts, Over/Under, 3-way]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import re

options = Options()
options.headless = False
web = 'https://fezbet1.com/en/sport?sportids=1'
path = r'C:\Users\Senne\Desktop\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'

options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
driver.get(web)
driver.maximize_window()

frame_ref = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0]
iframe = driver.switch_to.frame(frame_ref)

teams = []
x12 = []
btts = []
over_under = []
odds_events = []

rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'asb-flex- 
sc')))

for row in rows:
    odds = row.find_elements_by_class_name('asb-flex.asb- 
unshrink._asb_events-table-row-markets')
    try:
        empty_events = row.find_elements_by_class_name('_asb_prices- 
markets--price-block._asb_price-block')
        odds = [odd for odd in odds if odd not in empty_events]
    except:
        pass
    for n, odd in enumerate(odds[:3]):
        if n == 0:
            x12.append(odd.text)
            grandparent = 
odd.find_element_by_xpath('./..').find_element_by_xpath('./..')
            teams.append(grandparent.find_element_by_class_name('asb-flex- 
col.asb-pos-wide').text)
        if n == 1:
            over_under.append(odd.text)
        if n == 2:
            btts.append(odd.text)

#driver.quit()

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

dict_gambling = {'Teams' :teams, 'btts': btts,
             'Over/Under': over_under, '3-way': x12}

df_bwin = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_gambling)
df_bwin['Over/Under'] = df_bwin['Over/Under'].apply(lambda x:re.sub(',', 
'.', x))
df_bwin = df_bwin.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else 
x)

output = open('df_bwin', 'wb')
pickle.dump(df_bwin, output)
output.close()
print(df_bwin)
```

I dide so many reasearch but I still can't get it to work.
Thanks for you're time !